# Use monolog in composer package

Tags: php, logging, composer-php, monolog

I would like to use monolog in my own package installed via composer, but I do not understand, how this can be handled, in order to be compatible to any environment where the package is used.

What I want to achieve:

- Log important events and occurrences from the methods
- The developer should be able to read the logs with. e.g Monolog-Viewer

Problems:

- The log files directory is always different. So if I e.g. create a stream handler for this directory `$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(__DIR__ . '/../../../logs/myService.log', $this->logLevel));` it will be valid for **PHP Slim 3**, but not für **Laravel/Lumen**.
- Does exist any convention to handle these cases or a global variable with the log path if a monolog integration exists? Or do I have to define an own standard where the log file is placed?

Comment: I think you don't need choose logging library, you can use logger interface in your methods https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/

Comment: So when ever the user instantiates a class of the package, he needs to pass the logger interface of his environment? Thats what I found in [this tutorial about using PSR-3](https://www.sitepoint.com/logging-with-psr-3-to-improve-reusability/)

Comment: Yes if this is nessesary

Comment: Great, that seems to work well :-) Thanks

Comment: you're welcome:)